# Add value to Row for every column except one

Tags: python, pandas, insert, row, dataframe

I need to add "-1" value to every cell in a row except one. And I need to find this one depending on the name of the column, NOT THE NUMBER.

Example (this is supposed to be a row):

> 0 | 1 | 2 | -1 | 4 |

My code:

```
for i in myRange:
    P_total.ix[i] = [-1 for n in range(len(P_total.columns))]
```

This code adds "-1" to the whole row, how can I check if each specific column name contains "name" string in this for?

I know how to do this, but not inside a for:

```
if "name" not in exampleString:
    //any code
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Can you post raw input data, code to reproduce your df and desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `drop` for your `P_total.columns` and then subset with it your dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(632)
P_total = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5), columns=list('abcde'))

In [262]: P_total
Out[262]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -0.202506  1.245011   -1.787930 -1.076415
1  0.603727 -1.242478  0.430865 -1.689979  0.885975
2 -1.408643  0.545198 -1.351751 -0.095847  1.506013
3  1.454067 -1.081069 -0.162412 -0.141595 -1.180774
4 -0.578398  0.780636  0.873509 -1.373164 -0.956986
5  0.881837 -0.137655 -0.052613 -0.527390 -0.818549
6  1.401598  2.229587  0.312385 -0.009606  0.604757
7  0.286984 -0.210015  0.078443 -0.539372  1.910570
8  0.494034  1.302240  0.134238  0.741682  0.888207
9 -1.729944  0.179502 -1.386532  0.613595  0.594123

P_total.ix[0, P_total.columns.drop('c')] = -1

In [264]: P_total
Out[264]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0 -0.202506 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
1  0.603727 -1.242478  0.430865 -1.689979  0.885975
2 -1.408643  0.545198 -1.351751 -0.095847  1.506013
3  1.454067 -1.081069 -0.162412 -0.141595 -1.180774
4 -0.578398  0.780636  0.873509 -1.373164 -0.956986
5  0.881837 -0.137655 -0.052613 -0.527390 -0.818549
6  1.401598  2.229587  0.312385 -0.009606  0.604757
7  0.286984 -0.210015  0.078443 -0.539372  1.910570
8  0.494034  1.302240  0.134238  0.741682  0.888207
9 -1.729944  0.179502 -1.386532  0.613595  0.594123
```

Or you could do it without loop by subsetting your dataframe with that columns:

```
P_total[P_total.columns.drop('c')] = -1

In [266]: P_total
Out[266]:
   a  b         c  d  e
0 -1 -1  0.628800 -1 -1
1 -1 -1  0.430865 -1 -1
2 -1 -1 -1.351751 -1 -1
3 -1 -1 -0.162412 -1 -1
4 -1 -1  0.873509 -1 -1
5 -1 -1 -0.052613 -1 -1
6 -1 -1  0.312385 -1 -1
7 -1 -1  0.078443 -1 -1
8 -1 -1  0.134238 -1 -1
9 -1 -1 -1.386532 -1 -1
```

**EDIT**

If you need to filter your columns with name you could use `str.contains` method:

```
In [283]: P_total.columns
Out[283]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')

In [284]: P_total.columns.str.contains('a')
Out[284]: array([ True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

And then pass the result to the second field of the `ix` method:

```
your_columns = P_total.columns.str.contains('a')
P_total.ix[0, your_columns]
```

Comment: P_total.ix[i, P_total.columns.drop("idName")] = -1 worked  :) Thank you. (idName was the name of my column).